# c# how to proceed atomic get and set properties

Tags: c#, get, set, atomic, operation

i would like to ask about c# lang and get/set properties.

I have my console sw with timeout timer and serial link. In serial link i have timer which i use to detect timer overflow. Sometimes it happened that when i read the timer status using get (bool false) and in same time timer overflow and set variable to true. In this case for example this problem happened one times during several minutes (around 15min).

Is in c# some possibility how to use get/set properties like atomic operation?

**edit** found on other forum which should help:

```
private Object TimeoutLock = new Object();

public bool timeout {
    get { lock (TimeoutLock) { return Timeout; } } // critical section
    set { lock (TimeoutLock) { Timeout = value; } }
}
```

Comment: "in same time" is not a useful concept, think about it.

Comment: `Sometimes it happened that when i read the timer status using get (bool false) and in same time timer overflow and set variable to true` - and the issue here? What you want? reading / writing bool *is* atomic in C#

Comment: The problem is in case, when i reading variable and i use set and in same time i read same variable. Now i found     public bool timeout {
            get { lock (TimeoutLock) { return Timeout; } } // critical section
            set { lock (TimeoutLock) { Timeout = value; } }
        }

Comment: Accessing `bool` variable is atomic and doesn't require `lock`. Given edit doesn't make sense. Could you provide better example for the issue you are facing? [Multithreading](http://www.albahari.com/threading) is not easy, but maybe `readonly` field and reusing same timer is all you need ([Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) **is** threadsafe).